# nodejs: Error.captureStackTrace() adds stack, and I can access it, but I can't see it when I console log the error

Tags: javascript, node.js

here is a program I made called `example.js`

```
const e = {
  test: 'test',
};

console.log('object', e);
console.log('stack', e.stack);
console.log('now add stack trace info');
Error.captureStackTrace(e);
console.log('object', e);
console.log('stack', e.stack);
```

and when I run it, this is what I get:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node example.js 
object { test: 'test' }
stack undefined
now add stack trace info
object { test: 'test' }
stack Error
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pi/example.js:10:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ node --version
v12.18.3
```

so the `stack` property is added, and I can print it out individually, but it is hidden when I print the whole object.

When I `console.log(JSON.stringify(e));`, the `stack` field is still not visible.

How does that work?  Where is that field hidden?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

The `stack` property is set to be non-enumerable and so doesn't show up when the object's properties are enumerated as is done when using `JSON.stringify`.

## Long Answer

Object properties consist of a number of descriptors that control their value and how the system interacts with them. These include:

> `configurable`
>
> - `true` if the type of this property descriptor may be changed and if the property may be deleted from the corresponding object. Defaults to `false`.
>
> `enumerable`
>
> - `true` if and only if this property shows up during enumeration of the properties on the corresponding object. Defaults to `false`.
>
> `writable`
>
> - `true` if the value associated with the property may be changed with an assignment operator. Defaults to `false`.
>
> `value`
>
> - The value associated with the property. Can be any valid JavaScript value (number, object, function, etc). Defaults to `undefined`.

(There are also `get` and `set` as well as some configuration and behavioral rules but they're not important here. If you're interested, this is described on MDN under [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).)

Let's assume you have an object and you then assign to a previously non-existent property on that object:

```
const someObject = {};
someObject.someProperty = 'someValue';
```

This is similar to:

```
const someObject = {};
Object.defineProperty(someObject, 'someProperty', {
  configurable: true, 
  enumerable: true, 
  writable: true, 
  value: 'someValue',
});
```

When `Error.captureStackTrace` creates or updates the `stack` property on an object, it sets that property's `enumerable` descriptor to `false`. Because of this, `JSON.stringify` doesn't see the property when it enumerates over the object's properties.

## Solution

After calling `Error.captureStackTrace`, update the `stack` property's descriptors using `Object.defineProperty`, as in:

```
Object.defineProperty(e, 'stack', { enumerable: true });
```

This will cause the property to be enumerable so that `JSON.stringify` can see it.